# JQuery get cell value from row object

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a table with few rows, one of row has .active class, each cell of row has each class, in JQuery selecting table row with .active class, how can i get cell with specific class value/text ('.html()')

```js
var curentRow = $("#selectProduct tr.active);
    //how can i get from curentRow value/text of cell with class .prod_name?
```

```html
<table id="selectProduct" class="productTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Nr</td>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Buy Price</td>
    <td>Precent</td>
    <td>Sell Price</td>
    <td>Provider</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="">1</td>
    <td class="prod_id">1</td>
    <td class="prod_name">Product 1</td>
    <td class="buy_price">100</td>
    <td class="plus_percent">10</td>
    <td class="sell_price">110</td>
    <td class="provider_name">provider 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="active">
    <td class="">2</td>
    <td class="prod_id">2</td>
    <td class="prod_name">Product 2</td>
    <td class="buy_price">1000</td>
    <td class="plus_percent">10</td>
    <td class="sell_price">1100</td>
    <td class="provider_name">provider 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="">3</td>
    <td class="prod_id">3</td>
    <td class="prod_name">Product 3</td>
    <td class="buy_price">50</td>
    <td class="plus_percent">20</td>
    <td class="sell_price">60</td>
    <td class="provider_name">provider 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use function [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find the cell that you need in the row:

```
var curentRow = $("#selectProduct tr.active");
var yourCell = curentRow.find('.prod_id');
var value = yourCell.text();
```